# jquery modal window: loads content onclick first time; via php script subsequent times

Tags: jquery, dialog, modal-dialog

I'm using a login script that handles all error catching and feedback messages with php.  These messages send the user to a page outside of the website navigation, so I'm trying to get them to display in a jquery modal window.  I load the initial page onclick with the following code:

```
var dlg=$('#register').dialog({
        title: 'Register for LifeStor',
        resizable: true,
        autoOpen:false,
        modal: true,
        hide: 'fade',
        width:350,
        height:350
     });


     $('#reg_link').click(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         dlg.load('register.php', function(){
             dlg.dialog('open');
         });
      });
```

This works fine -- the script loads, and the user can fill out registration information.  When they submit that info, a php feedback message is generated with this code:

```
function procLogin(){
      global $session, $form;
      /* Login attempt */
      $retval = $session->login($_POST['user'], $_POST['pass'], isset($_POST['remember']));

      /* Login successful */
      if($retval){
         //header("Location: ".$session->referrer);
        header('Location:userhome(2).php');

      }
      /* Login failed */
      else{
         $_SESSION['value_array'] = $_POST;
         $_SESSION['error_array'] = $form->getErrorArray();
         header("Location: ".$session->referrer);
      }
   }
```

I changed the header("Location") line to:
    header("Location: lifestor2.html:);

which is the homepage that has the hidden div where the modal box lives.  This sort of works!  It replaces the content of the modal dialog with the feedback msg (which is on yet another php page).  However, because the modal dialog is launched onclick (see above), you have to click the link again to see the feedback message.

So, my question: Is there a way to launch a modal dialog onclick the first time, then have it autoOpen subsequently?  I don't want to mess around too much with the php scripting as it is very layered and complex.  If I can get the right messages to display in the modal, that would be perfect.

Regards...